# MacTex 2019 graphics doesn't render properly

Tags: crop, ghostscript, latexit

I just upgraded MacTex from 2018 to 2019 using HomeBrew, the graphics didn't render well(very blur compared with the earlier version, guess it is about some changes on the default graphics resolution configuration maybe), so I had it uninstalled and downloaded the whole package from http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and installed it again. Well, now it has a new problem, improper cropping.

For a simple tex,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main~Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
$ abcdefg $
\end{document}
```

LaTeXiT shows a incomplete graphic like this:
[image]

Then I tried to render it from the console with pdflatex and pdfcrop, the pdf seems to be fine while the cropped version is like the one above.

pdflatex:
[image]

pdfcrop:
[image]

And here is the debug info of pdfcrop:

```
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* Restricted mode: disabled
* Option `pdfversion': auto
* Perl executable: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl
* Perl version: v5.28.1
* Pointer size: 8
* Pipe support: yes
* Fork support: yes
* OS name: darwin
* Arch name: darwin-thread-multi-2level
* System: unix
* Not found (gs): /usr/local/sbin/gs
* Not found (gs): /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/gs
* Not found (gs): /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/gs
* Not found (gs): /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/gs
* Not found (gs): <my-user-folder>/rmac/bin/gs
* Found (gs): /usr/local/bin/gs
* Autodetected ghostscript command: gs
* Input file: a.pdf
* Output file: a-crop.pdf
* Margins: 0 0 0 0
* PDF header: %PDF-1.5
* Using PDF minor version: 5
* Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
* Ghostscript call: gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f a.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 144 651 177 659
* Page 1: 144 651 177 659
%%HiResBoundingBox: 144.557996 651.347980 176.705995 658.961980
* Running pdfTeX ...
* pdfTeX call: pdftex -no-shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode tmp-pdfcrop-2173
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdftex)
entering extended mode
(./tmp-pdfcrop-2173.tex [1 <./a.pdf>] )
Output written on tmp-pdfcrop-2173.pdf (1 page, 11402 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp-pdfcrop-2173.log.
==> 1 page written on `a-crop.pdf'.
* Cleanup
* Temporary files: tmp-pdfcrop-2173.tex tmp-pdfcrop-2173.log
```

I didn't met such issues in MacTex 2017 or 2018 version. Did any issues happened during gs bounding box calculation? Could any one please shed some light on this? It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in gs 9.27. See https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/63, https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700988, and https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700952

Comment: Many thanks, @David Purton, you are right. After read the link, I decided to use gs 9.26 (latest version from HomeBrew), and the cropping issue was gone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is to do with a (now fixed upstream) bug in GhostScript.

Comment: @David Purton，please let me know if anything I can do to close this，thanks.